# NicEdit.js is not working after Ajax page reload

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using simple Rich Text editor 'nicEdit' to change all my textarea into rich-text editor. it works fine for the dom ready and page load. after an AJAX refresh the textarea will be back, the nicedit is not working .

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

This is the JS code I got it from the nicedit. After the Ajax call , again I called it like this.

```
new nicEditor();
```

Any helps to run it again after the  AJAX Call.

Comment: Someone please help me.